# "Orte, wo man Geburtstag feiern kann"

Tags: word-choice, relative-clause

Are all of these ways to say "Places where you can celebrate your birthday" correct? Which sentence sounds the best?

1. Orte, wo man (seinen) Geburtstag feiern kann.
2. Orte, an denen man (seinen) Geburtstag feiern kann.
3. Orte zum Geburtstag feiern.

Also, in examples 1 and 2, should I use seinen or not?

Comment: In the current form this question may be closed as asking for opinions. Why not offer your choice and the reasons for it? This would enhance the question significantly.

Answer (score 1):

First off: all three variants are not "sentences" - at least not complete ones! But then, the english template you worked from isn't a sentence either. A sentence would be:

> Places where you can celebrate your birthday *are hard to find*.

and hence:

> Orte an denen man Geburtstag feiern kann sind schwer zu finden.

But maybe you meant to ask not about the correctness of these *sentences* but these *phrases*? (If so: it would be nice if you could edit your question to reflect this.)

Now, all three phrases are - in a colloqial sense - correct. In a written text you should use number 2.

"Orte, wo", like in 1, is a poor choice of words and considered a stylistic error. "Orte, an denen", as in 2 is preferable.

"Orte zum Feiern" (3) is also a poor choice, which can be used (and is even common) in spoken language but I'd rather not use it in written text.

Your second question, about using "seinen": yes, that is correct. The "man" has no real counterpart in English, the closest are constructions with "one" and there also the generic masculine pronoun is used - a common trait of indo-european langugages, e.g.

> a place where one can celebrate **his** birthday

Notice this "generic masculine" is true with other indefinite constructions, in English and in German alike:

> Jemand hat **seine** Tasche liegenlassen.
> Somebody has left **his** bag.

Notice though, that it changes the meaning a bit: without the "seinen" you ask about places where the celebration is possible, with the "seinen" about places where one can celebrate *his own* birthday. (thanks @O. R. Mapper for the catch)

Comment: 'Your second question, about using "seinen": yes, that is correct.' - well, it does change the meaning a bit.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: correct, I have edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: A distinction that is probably mostly relevant to parents of young children ;)